# Angular 2 form controls with a display name and a value different

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I'm developing a form but I need to display something different than the content.

I got:

```
<ion-label>Rate</ion-label>
     <ion-input text-right detail-push formControlName="rate" type="text"
          placeholder="00.00"
          [(ngModel)]="rateDisplay" disabled>
     </ion-input>
```

Then I access my form like this:

```
if(!this.clientAction.isRateFormEmpty()){
  this.clientForm.controls['rate'].setValue(this.clientAction.getRateForm());
  this.rateDisplay = this.clientAction.getRateFormToDisplay();
}
```

The think is from **getRateForm()** I receive an object and on the form it displays [Object Object], I understand that's normal because that's my value and it needs to be an object, because I need to send this object later on my submit method.

But with **getRateFormToDisplay()** I receive a string that I would like to show on the input.

Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I finally found a solution.

I created a second input "hidden" where I placed the return of **getRateForm()**

Then on the second input, I displayed the return of **getRateFormToDisplay()** but I "disabled" this input so I don't get the data out from the form.

```
<ion-input text-right detail-push 
   formControlName="rate" 
   type="text" 
   hidden>
</ion-input>
<ion-input text-right detail-push 
   formControlName="rateDisplay" type="text"
   placeholder="00.00"
   [(ngModel)]="rateDisplay">
</ion-input>
```

And on my typescript file:

```
this.clientForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  rate: [this.rateForm],
  rateDisplay: [{value: '00:00', disabled: true}],
});
```

Maybe it will help one of you one day.